# Remove last characters before file extension

Tags: windows, file, unix, rename, command-prompt

I am trying to *remove the last 4 characters of a series of files* (in a folder) before the file extension (.tiff).

For example, instead of :

> TAG_20_5K_SAMPLE_651.tiff

I would like:

> TAG_20_5K_SAMPLE.tiff (Remove _651)

I have tried using this:

```
rename -n 's/(.*).{12}/$1/' *
```

**Source:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/873617/remove-last-n-characters-of-filenames-for-all-files-in-a-directory

But I am getting this error:

```
C:\...\Test1>rename -n 's/(.*).{4}/$1/' *
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: Use double quotes. `cmd` doesn't understand `'...'`.

Comment: The Windows `rename` command doesn't understand patterns. It's just `rename FROM TO`.

Comment: I tried with double quotes, it doesn't work either :/ How could I go about with it? I have windows terminal and cygwin. Tried the same on Cgywin but got the same error. :/

Comment: @melpomene [it does support patterns](https://superuser.com/q/475874/241386) although with complex pattern rules

Comment: @MedImage `rename` or `ren` in Windows is **not** Linux's rename. Run `ren /?` to see